# Beamer: page number without footer

Tags: beamer, spacing, page-numbering, footer, beamer-metropolis

I am preparing a beamer presentation using the metropolis theme. In some slides, I would like to add text at the very bottom of the slide. This is done adding

```
\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}
```

in the preamble and

```
\begin{frame}
 framecontent

 \btVFill

 text at the bottom of the slide. 
 \end{frame}
```

This works exactly as I suppose, as long as my footer is absent, i.e., as long as I define in the preamble

```
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[]{}
```

I would like, however, to have the frame numbers from the footer environment put at the bottom right corner, such as resulting from

```
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
```

If I add the footer, the btVfill command will move the text just "above" the space occupied by the footer (being empty, considering my minimalistic definition of the footer).

Do you have any suggestion on how easily put text the very bottom of my slide keeping the minimal footer? A solutions which would not use the vspace command, as I would need to adjust it in each and every slide.

Thanks for your suggestions,
Leo

Comment: Can you make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 4):

Misusing the navigation symbols, one could do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 framecontent

 \btVFill

 text at the bottom of the slide. 
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]