# How to number slides in the beamer theme Berkeley?

Tags: beamer

How to enumerate each slide using the theme Berkeley without the final part of the index having a blank piece?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please add a full compileable code.

Comment: What does "without the final part of the index having a blank piece"  refer to?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432287/beamer-page-number-without-footer/432319#432319)?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly. The minimal code is as follows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
   text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{title}
   text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**OR**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
   text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{title}
   text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]